# Command runs fine on command line but not from Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-7-x64

**PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 7 64-bit**

When I tested out in a shell, the following works fine:

```
powershell -command { sleep 5 }
```

But when I have this in a Scheduled Task, with `powershell` in the Program box and `-command { sleep 5 }` in the Argument box, Task Scheduler reports "The operation completed successfully. (0x0)" but nothing is run.

I had to record the screen with a video camera and then played back in slow motion to find out what is going on. After the PowerShell profile script runs, `sleep 5` shows on the screen with no error and PowerShell closes immediately.

(Both my x86 and x64 versions have ExecutionPolicy set to RemoteSigned.)

What do I have to do to make `-command` work in Task Scheduler?
.

Comment: The problem is that Task Scheduler runs the command using the default shell, which unfortunately is still cmd. To test a command for Task Scheduler, run it at a cmd prompt instead of a PowerShell prompt. If you try `powershell -command { sleep 5 }` in cmd, you'll see exactly what you saw when Task Scheduler ran it. But if you use quotes instead of curly braces as suggested in the answer below, it will wait for 25 seconds as desired.

Comment: Thanks. I can reproduce what you described running from cmd and it is similar to what I saw in the Task Scheduler output.

Comment: The command line syntax help for powershell specifically states that you can specify a script block for the -Command parameter only when running powershell.exe from within PowerShell. You could pass a script block from cmd like this: `"& {<code>}"`. But there's no point in doing that if it works just as well without the ampersand and curly braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `powershell -Command "sleep 5"` instead.